# read data from CSV file

Tags: c++, file, csv

I want to add some data from CSV document, to my program, however there is one trouble.

#### data.csv

> Article,dangerLevel,OpenDate,openTime,closeDate,Close;
> Time,spentTime,timeLeft 54,1,05/03/2015,10:00,06/03/2015,15:00,29,43;
> 55,2,05/03/2015,10:00,06/03/2015,15:00,15,77;
> 55,2,05/03/2015,10:00,06/03/2015,15:00,12,70;

#### main.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
            char data_component_opened[100];
            char buffer[1000];
            FILE *fp;
            fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");
                fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);


                int i       = 0;
                int n       = 0;
                int row     = 0;
                int col     = 0;
                for(i=0;i < 1000;i++){
                    if(buffer[i] == ';'){
                        row++;
                        col = 0;
                    }
                    if(buffer[i] == ','){
                        col++;
                        n = 0;
                    }
                    if(row == 1 && col == 2){
                        printf("%c", buffer[i]);
                        n++;
                    }
                }


            fclose(fp);
}
```

When I compile this code I expected "05/03/2015", but got "Å", like there is some encoding mistake (like russian text saved in ASCII).

Comment: Are you sure about the format of the data.csv file ? It looks strange.

Comment: And why do you not use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)? This would be more appropriate to read a file line by line.

Comment: So each line is a semi-colon separated list, and each element in the list is in turn a list (comma separated this time)? Then I suggest you use those facts, and read one line at a time, separate each line on semi-colon, and then separate on comma.

Comment: Also, the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function might be good here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I need get an col and row in variables to operate it easer. 
and data.csv is saved in LibreOffice calc and then i just add ";" in line end.

Comment: Lastly, the only C++ specific code you have in the source you show are the included header files, the `using namespace std;` statement, and the lonely `cout`. All the rest is basically C code. If you want to program C++ the I recommend you look up [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [the C++ input and output stream library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: Your program do nothing. You iterate over i and you check if row == 1. But row == 0, so you'll never write any char in `data_component_opened`.

Comment: @Fefux 

'
                for(i=0;i < 1000;i++){
                    if(buffer[i] == ';'){
                        row++;
                        col = 0;
                    }
                    if(buffer[i] == ','){
                        col++;
                        n = 0;
                    }
                    if(row == 1 && col == 2){
                        data_component_opened[n] = buffer[i];
                        n++;
                    }
                }' I changed for loop to this, but nothing changed

Comment: If your "data.csv" is really a Excel Text file, why not reading it as a text file using `fopen("data.csv", "rt");` and `fgets()` instead of `fread()` ?

Comment: Please read the manuel of fread : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread, you inverted size of element and number of element. I suggest also to check if `fp != NULL` and the return value of `fread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i too had recently worked on csv file project.

I had used getline function to get one line from the file

Since i was using a "\n 'function in place of your ";"

i used the default `getline(file_name,string_name)`

What you could do is use `getline(file_name,string_name,';')`

where file_name is the name of the file pointer you open normally.

Using getline in a loop gets you all the subsequent lines.

This string gets you the line as is with the comma separated entries .

so i created a function to separate the string on basis of the comma

Here is the function

```
//The first input is the number of strings you need to separate
//Article,dangerLevel,OpenDate,openTime,closeDate,Close; means A is 6
//Second input is the line itself from the getline function
//Third imput is the index of the string you want 

string strsplit(int v,string s,int j)
{
    string a[v];
    //Setting delimiter to "," premanently
    string delim=",";
    int start;
    int end;
    start = 0;
    end = s.find(delim);
    int i=0;
    while (end <=s.length())
    {   a[i]=s.substr(start, end - start);
        start = end + delim.length();
        end = s.find(delim, start);
        i++;
    }
    //For the last part of the sequence.
    a[i]=s.substr(start, end);
    return a[j];
}
```

Comment: What is the link between `getline(file_name,string_name)` and the described `string strsplit(int v,string s,int j)` ? Even if the post is **"C++"** marked, the **"@Цунский Никита"** provided source code of `main()` is **"Standard C"**.

Comment: the string that we get from getline() is put into the delimiter function to the different parts.

Saw the using namespace std;

Comment: assumed its c++